# a.s. convergence uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I am having troubles with proving almost surely convergence for the following problem:

Let $U_j$ be IID $U(0,1)$ distributed and define $A_n$ to be:

$A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^k U_j$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

for $n\rightarrow \infty$, I want to prove that $A_n$ converges almost surely to some $A$.

I tried with LLN, but this did not give anything.

Comment: I have edited the question making two small changes. I hope I didn't ruin anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $A_n$ is an increasing sequence of random variables, and therefore the pointwise limit equals $$A=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n.$$ In order to show that this limit is well-defined (in the sense $A<\infty$ a.s.) we note that by the monotone convergence theorem

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}(A_n) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty,$$

and so $A \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$. This implies, in particular, $A<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Everything makes sense, thank you! But what is the space L^1(P)? And is there a "general technique" to prove almost surely convergence, because I am often struggling with that. Or just some tips to consider?

Comment: @JonathanKiersch $A \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$ means simply that $A$ has finite expectation, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(|A|)<\infty$. Re your 2nd question: Well, no, unfortunately there is no general technique. Often it helps to analyze the structure of the sequence; for instance if $A_n = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j$ then you can use different techniques depending whether the random variables $Y_j$ are independent and/or identically distributed. For independent random variables it's worth trying Kolmogorov's series theorem or Lévy's theorem ... if they are additionally identically distributed, then the strong law of

Comment: large numbers is a good idea. The most difficult case is that the random variables $(Y_j)$ are not independent or $(A_n)$ doesn't have this particular structure...then, for instance, sometimes the Borel-Cantelli lemma is useful. In the end, the only thing which helps is to keep solving such exercises... it certainly helps to get a better intuition.

Comment: I see, Thank you. Very helpful!

Comment: @JonathanKiersch You are welcome.